# C++ MFC Serializre(CArchive &ar) with CArray<class*, class*>

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, serialization, mfc

I have a program,draws shapes: Lozenge, square, rectangle, line, circle... it's same Paint in Microsoft.
My problems are save and load file with Serialize(CArchive &), but i cannot save and load file when use CArray. How i can do that:

```
class BaseShape : public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(BaseShape)
public:
    CPoint topLeft, bottomRight;
    COLORREF m_clrBack;
    EShapeType m_ShapeType;  //enum type of shape
public:
    BaseShape(void);  //empty method
    BaseShape (CPoint , CPoint, COLORREF, EShapeType);
    ~BaseShape(void);
    virtual void DrawShape (CDC*);  //empty method
    void Serialize(CArchive& ar);
};
```

Implement Serialize(CArchive& ar) of BaseShape class:

```
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(BaseShape, CObject, 1)
void BaseShape::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsStoring())
        {
            ar << topLeft << bottomRight << m_clrBack << m_ShapeType;
        }
        else
        {
            int temp_shape;
            ar >> topLeft >> bottomRight >> m_clrBack >> temp_shape;
            m_ShapeType = (EShapeType)temp_shape;
        }
    }
```

Square class and Lozenge class are derived by BaseShape:

```
class CSquare : public BaseShape
{
public:
    CSquare(void);
    CSquare (CPoint , CPoint, COLORREF, EShapeType);
    ~CSquare(void);
    void DrawShape(CDC*);
};
```

In MFC Document class, i have:

```
//declare properties
  CArray<BaseShape*, BaseShape*> m_arrShape;
        COLORREF m_clrBack;
        EShapeType m_ShapeType;

//implement method

void CdemoDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        int i;
        ar << m_arrShape.GetSize();
        for (i = 0; i <m_arrShape.GetSize(); i++)
            ar << m_arrShape[i];
    }
    else
    {
        int ncount, i;
        ar >> ncount;
        m_arrShape.RemoveAll();
        for (i = 0; i < ncount; i++)
        {
            BaseShape* pShape = new BaseShape();
            ar >> pShape;
            m_arrShape.Add(pShape);
        }
```

above my code, **When i click open file, the shapes is not showed, which was drew before, although my code are not error**, I save data file uncertain successfuly. I dont understand how the code lines of "isloading()" function working. Is there another way to do it ? This is my source code for all my project: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jy23ct28bgqybdc/demo.rar

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is. Is it a compile problem, a link problem, or a runtime problem you are having trouble with?

Comment: I can not save and load file by serialize (CArchive &) method in MFC doc/view aplication.

Comment: But what is the specific problem? Have you debugged it?

Comment: Yes, i have ! I was run my project, it still draw the shapes, but i cant load file, which was saved when i click open file

Comment: You can download my project to debug it

Comment: What happens? Is an exception thrown? Debug what happens in the line *ar >> pShape;*

Comment: Did you debug it with Visual Studio's debugger ?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 Ultimate to develop this project. I'm still save data file normaly. But when I open file, it dont show the shapes as was drew.

Comment: Your sample code, doesn't match the code you provided in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: You can not create a BaseShape object and expect that it get specialized when it is loaded.

The trick is that ar << saves the complete object type and saves the Name of the class in the stream to. All you need is to load the stream into an object pointer again. The CArchive code will try to find a matching object class creates it and loads it.

Please read the [MSDN about CObject serializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bfsbt0t.aspx)... se also the Scribble samples and others.

```
if (ar.IsStoring())
{
  int i;
  ar << m_arrShape.GetSize();
  for (i = 0; i <m_arrShape.GetSize(); i++)
    ar << m_arrShape[i];
}
else
{
  int ncount, i;
  ar >> ncount;
  m_arrShape.RemoveAll();
  for (i = 0; i < ncount; i++)
  {
    BaseShape *pNewShape;
    ar >> pNewShape;
    m_arrShape.Add(pNewShape);
  }
}
```

PS: If you provide sample code, it should match the code in your question.

Comment: you dont understand my problem. BaseShape like abstract class, I want to save data of inherited class. And I cant do it !

Comment: I understand completely! When m_arrShape contains objects of the specialized classes, than  ar>>pNewShape will create the derived classes. Please add apprompriate DECLARE_SERIAL/IMPLEMENT handler to your specialized classes. Please read the links I gave to you!!!!

Comment: Sure that you didn't used an old file? Write anew file after you redeclared the classes.

Comment: In your link, I dont understand the embedded class, What do it use to be ? In my project, I dont have that class type, I have 2 class inherited from BaseShape class.

Comment: I declare IMPLEMENT_SERIAL in implement file of Document class, it's ok. But I run project to check, I drew new file to save, I click open it notice "Unxpected file format". Why system show that ?

Comment: This message is shown when the serialization failed. So reading the data and creating the object failed. You may see more info in the debug output.

Comment: Debug output ? I dont understand you told! I open the save file to see code, but it is not binary type.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I sovled my problem.